# Python copy files from specific child folder

Tags: python, shutil

I have folder structure like below:

```
document/v00/id_001/..
document/v00/id_002/..
document/v01/id_011/..
document/v01/id_012/..
document/v02/id_021/..
document/v02/id_022/..
```

Is there any way for me to copy child folder without specifying the parent folder?

I have tried this:

```
shutil.copytree ("document/*/id_012", "destination")
```

Note that I replace parent folder with * in the example above which obviously not working.

Comment: Why do you need python?  `cp -r document/*/id_012 destination/.` should work from a shell.

Comment: Yes I know it is working from a shell. But the example here is only the snippet of my phyton code. Hence need to do it in pyhton ;-)

Comment: What happened when you tried that python code?  Did it cause an error?  Did it not copy any files?  Did it copy some files, but not all?  Did it copy them to the wrong location?  Saying that something "did not work" is not an adequate description of the actual problem.